# Setting base directory for Apache Alias and static resource files

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, static, resources, alias

I have been searching for an answer to this everywhere, and I can't seem to find any simple solution for this. I can't understand why such a simple thing should be so complicated.

So basically - what I want to do is to map up a few local sites on my apache, each of them having their own css/js etc. Then in my apache conf I set up a few Aliases:

```
# site 1
Alias /site1 "C:/www/site1"
<Directory "C:/www/site1">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

# site 2
Alias /site1 "C:/www/site2"
<Directory "C:/www/site2">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Now, when I go to the url: `http://localhost/site1/`, the content for site1 will be served - index.html is being loaded. All fine. Within my files I am linking css and js from folders using absolute paths - for example `/css/styles.css` and `/js/scripts.js`.

When these files are being served through apache they will get the following path:

`http://localhost/css/styles.css` (ignoring the 'site1'), and the reason is of course since I've asked to go from my webroot 'localhost' by specifying an absolute path.

Why absolute paths? I need to be able to move my .html files deeper into the folder structure of my sites - meaning that in relation to where they are - they cannot know where the resource files are - unless I can tell them to start from a certain point - the web root.

So the question is:

Isn't there any easy way of telling my Alias setup, that any file being asked for - using the absolute path, shoud start with `http://localhost/sitex/*` instead of just `http://localhost/*`. In other words, the base path is changed.

I've tried AliasMatch, DirectoryMatch, RewriteRules RewriteBase, but all seemingly unable to change this.

Maybe I should be using something other than Alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try read very carefully the Apache RewriteRule documentation.
If you want to change something you need to understand those fundamentals things (I give you my "many days of tries and search" here):

- `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is different from `REQUEST_URI`. If you apply some rewrite rules and you change the URI then you need to compare to `SCRIPT_FILENAME`, because `REQUEST_URI` will **never** change (from my own experiments, but I may be wrong)
- if you put a whole filename (e.g. `/web/htdocs/olivier/zer/szzae/Symfony/web/app.php`) in your rewrite rules, instead of *relative* URI then this will be treated differently in the comparisons, and in the rewrite rules.

So, for your need, maybe what you're trying to do technically is not the right way to solve your problems.

You could do something like (not tried, but I'm using some of it in my websites):

```
# if this is a static file, extract the extension into `EXT`:
RewriteRule (.*)(\.(css|js|txt|pdf|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico))$ $1$2 [NC,QSA,E=EXT:$3]
# .. do some processing then ..
# if the file is css or js (modify it for your needs)
RewriteCond %{ENV:EXT} (css|js|txt)$
# then here's the hint that may save your life!!
# rewrite the file to "previous" content
# AND whole filename, *not* relative URI
RewriteRule  ^(.+) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/..%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [QSA,L]
```

You may add a condition: if file is found in your "base" directory, then override, otherwise let Apache treat it "naturally" (= try to get it from the website itself):

```
# checks if it exists, and if so then
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/..%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule  ^(.+) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/..%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [QSA,L]
```

NB: I've not tested: try with either `/..%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` or `/../%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` (note the **`/`**)

And now time for reading: read passthrough directive [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt).

Hope this helps!